# TensorFlow Object Detection API augmentations

Tags: tensorflow, crop, image-resizing, object-detection-api, data-augmentation

I'm curious about the order of resizing and augmentations in the TensorFlow object detection API. For example, I'm using the config file `ssd_mobilenet_v2_oid_v4.config`. This uses `fixed_shape_resizer` and `ssd_random_crop`. So what is the interaction between these two modules?

Does the `ssd_random_crop` take a crop of the size defined in `fixed_shape_resizer`? If resizing happens first, then what size are the crops after resizing? And I assume they all need to be the same exact size in order to create proper batches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data augmentation happens before resizing. All preprocessing steps are specified in function `transform_input_data` in file [inputs.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/inputs.py), this file contains functions like `create_train_input_fn`, `create_eval_input_fn` and `create_predict_input_fn` that will feed input image tensors to the model during training, evaluation and prediction. In [`create_train_input_fn`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/5c37e69cf1e3fb053380a15b1df79a2813c6b5c3/research/object_detection/inputs.py#L426), the following transform function is used.

```
def transform_input_data(tensor_dict,
                         model_preprocess_fn,
                         image_resizer_fn,
                         num_classes,
                         data_augmentation_fn=None,
                         merge_multiple_boxes=False,
                         retain_original_image=False,
                         use_multiclass_scores=False,
                         use_bfloat16=False):
  """A single function that is responsible for all input data transformations.
  Data transformation functions are applied in the following order.
  1. If key fields.InputDataFields.image_additional_channels is present in
     tensor_dict, the additional channels will be merged into
     fields.InputDataFields.image.
  2. data_augmentation_fn (optional): applied on tensor_dict.
  3. model_preprocess_fn: applied only on image tensor in tensor_dict.
  4. image_resizer_fn: applied on original image and instance mask tensor in
     tensor_dict.
  5. one_hot_encoding: applied to classes tensor in tensor_dict.
  6. merge_multiple_boxes (optional): when groundtruth boxes are exactly the
     same they can be merged into a single box with an associated k-hot class
     label.
  Args:
    tensor_dict: dictionary containing input tensors keyed by
      fields.InputDataFields.
    model_preprocess_fn: model's preprocess function to apply on image tensor.
      This function must take in a 4-D float tensor and return a 4-D preprocess
      float tensor and a tensor containing the true image shape.
    image_resizer_fn: image resizer function to apply on groundtruth instance
      `masks. This function must take a 3-D float tensor of an image and a 3-D
      tensor of instance masks and return a resized version of these along with
      the true shapes.
    num_classes: number of max classes to one-hot (or k-hot) encode the class
      labels.
    data_augmentation_fn: (optional) data augmentation function to apply on
      input `tensor_dict`.
    merge_multiple_boxes: (optional) whether to merge multiple groundtruth boxes
      and classes for a given image if the boxes are exactly the same.
    retain_original_image: (optional) whether to retain original image in the
      output dictionary.
    use_multiclass_scores: whether to use multiclass scores as
      class targets instead of one-hot encoding of `groundtruth_classes`.
    use_bfloat16: (optional) a bool, whether to use bfloat16 in training.
  Returns:
    A dictionary keyed by fields.InputDataFields containing the tensors obtained
    after applying all the transformations.
  """
```

The data augmentation is performed on step 2 (if there are any) and resizing is performed on step 4.